# Orientation preserving/reversing homeomorphisms of torus

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I know that every matrix $A$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ gives raise to a homeomorphism of the torus which induces a linear map $H_1(\mathbb{T}) \longrightarrow H_1(\mathbb{T})$ whose associated matrix is precisely $A$.

My problem is that I need to determine if the homeomorphism $f_A$ associated to $A$ is orientation preserving (i.e. $\textrm{deg }f = 1$) or orientation reversing (i.e. $\textrm{deg }f=-1$). Is there any easy approach (e.g. using smoothnes) to decide so in terms of the entries of $A$?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the sign of $\det A$. Indeed, the action of the map of the torus
on the second homology group $H_2(T)$ is precisely multiplication by $\det A$.

Comment: This is a really nice point of view +1

Comment: I don't see why the action on 2nd homology group is multiplcation by determinant...

Comment: @J.Karen you can prove it by using the homology cross product.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about that!

Answer (score 3):

Take the determinant. If it is $-1$, then it is orientation reversing, if it is $1$, it is orientation preserving.

any element $T \in \mathbb SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ has the property that  for any real numbers $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $m,n \in \mathbb Z$, we have $T(x+m,y+n)=T(x,y)+T(m^{\prime},n^{\prime})$ for some integers $m^{\prime},n^{\prime})$. However, $\mathbb R^2$ is the universal cover for the torus, and this condition means exactly that in the covering map $p:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb T$, this map also descends to some homeomorphism $\tilde{T}: \mathbb T \to \mathbb T$, since it is well defined in the quotient.

Since the determinant on $\mathbb R^2$ measures the signed area of the image of the unit square, we can see that when it is negative, the orientation reversing transformation descends via the covering map to $\mathbb T$.